# Building OSX gcc code in Travis

Tags: xcode, macos, travis-ci, sqlcipher

I'm sure someone has ran into this before, but I'm having a very hard time finding it.  I have a travis build script for compiling an xcode project and part of it needs to use sqlcipher which compiles using scripts.  When it gets to that portion in travis I see:

```
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/travis/build/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/vendor/sqlcipher':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I've found multiple threads saying that gcc-4.8 should already be installed, although trying "export CC=gcc-4.8" fails and using compgen has not helped to find what version it should be.

My current .travis.yml file looks like:

```
language: objective-c

compiler:
  - gcc

script:
  - cd "exampleProjects/IncrementalStore"
  # 32-bit tests
  - xctool -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme "Incremental Store Demo" clean test -destination "name=iPhone Retina (4-inch)"
  # 64-bit tests
  - xctool -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme "Incremental Store Demo" clean test -destination "name=iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"

before_install: 
  - brew update
  - brew unlink xctool
  - brew install xctool
```

And trying to brew install of gcc times-out, and seems like there should be a simpler fix.

Comment: How about `CC=clang ./configure`?

Comment: Good suggestion @droppy, unfortunately now the entire make process fails (even the clean step).  I've seen that before in my initial attempts to use gcc-4.8 which didn't exist.

Comment: Is there a log file generated?  That might show a more specific error message as to why it is unable to compile a C program.

Comment: A little late with this, but the full log should be here: https://travis-ci.org/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/builds/37857257
Any insight would be appreciated, still not found a good solution.